# Where do the H+ ions come from in light reactions?

Tags: molecular-biology, metabolism, photosynthesis

In the light-dependent reactions of photosynthesis, H<sup>+</sup> ions pass to the thylakoid space. Where do these protons come from?

Comment: Photolysis of water. It is the first step of the light reactions. BTW, H⁺ is ubiquitous.

Comment: And the electrons go to PhotoSystem II?

Comment: Is this a homework question? It really looks much like it. Additionally: Please have a look at the reaction chart on the Wikipedia page on photosynthesis which explains both questions.

Comment: No, I have a biology course in Univeristy, and I just want to be sure I know it before the exam.

Comment: @Benjli Read our homework policy. If you have not put an effort in answering a basic question then we consider it as homework. Can you add some points on how you analysed this problem?

Comment: All right, I will keep the homework policy in mind. But again: that question was not a part of any homework. I had tried to search it in my biology book. It was written in it that electrons come from water to Photosystem II only when there are no electrons left in it, but H+ ions are being passed into the thyalkoid space even when there are enough electrons left in the photosystem! So I tried to solve the contradiction.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think you meant H+ (not H-) is ubiquitous. H+ is everywhere in the aqueous system. H- is pretty rare and unstable in aqueous/biological systems, that's why there's NADPH.

Answer (score 3):

The photolysis of water is coupled to the reduction of plastaquinone (Q) in photosystem II (PSII) as summarized in this diagram, adapted from [Berg *et al.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22538/):

[image: Establishment of hydrogen ion gradient in photosynthesis]

The overall reaction (which balances) is:

2 H<sub>2</sub>O + 2 Q + 4 H<sup>+</sup> = O<sub>2</sub> + 2 QH<sub>2</sub> + 4 H<sup>+</sup>

But the 4 H<sup>+</sup> on both sides of the equation are not the same. The generation of the hydrogen ions in the thylakoid lumen is coupled to the uptake of hydrogen ions from the stroma as the plastoquinone is reduced. This is made possible because of the membrane disposition of the components of photosystem II. Hence an electochemical gradient is established that can be used for generating the ATP needed for photosynthesis.