# Is there nothing such as NADPH2?

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis

I have gone through various sites and some say there is NADPH2 and some say there is no NADPH2 there's only NADP+ ...WHich is the correct view....Please dont mark this answer as duplicates since I have asked a similar question related to photosynthesis in the past but there too I have not received any satisfactory answer bythe community .

Comment: If you didn't got satisfactory answers, you should work on your question. You can always edit them (unless you totally change the question *after* you got an answer).

Comment: Might be useful if you could give links to sites that use NAPH2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this implicitly in a comment to my answer to: [Light and Dark Reaction of photosynthesis?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45387/light-and-dark-reaction-of-photosynthesis/45401#45401). Anyway:

There is no such thing as NADPH<sub>2</sub>. There is only NADP<sup>+</sup> and NADPH. Consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide_phosphate) or a reputable text such as [Berg](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22398/).

The nicotinamide portion of NADP that  undergoes oxidation and reduction is exactly the same as in NAD. The changes undergone are:

[image: NAD(P) redox]

The error either comes from confusion with the other redox cofactor, FAD / FADH<sub>2</sub>, or the fact that two electrons are involved in the reduction of NADP:

> NADP<sup>+</sup> + H<sup>+</sup> + 2e → NADPH

Comment: Apologies that my initial answer was just in terms of NAD, not NADP. Fixed now.

Comment: A factor that sometimes is confusing is that both hydrogens at the redox site in NADP(H) are equivalent. So it is possible that one hydrogen gets added in the reduction, but the other hydrogen is donated in the next oxidation, and therefore deuterium tracing studies of NAD(P)H will give both +1 and +2 deuterium isotopes. This is sometimes mistakenly interpreted as "NADPH2".